# What kind of spider is this from Sydney, Australia?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, arachnology

I was cleaning the pool when this guy crawled on my foot. I hit him away and noticed a bite mark. I managed to snap a photo of him.

[image: Side view]

I went to the doctor because I was worried it was a funnel web and she told me to just keep an eye on it, ice it and take anti histamines if it itches.

I have a tiny bit of tenderness in my foot.

[image: Rear view]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good news is that this is definitely not a funnel web spider (Atracinae), which, by the way, is not that dangerous✻.

The image doesn't have a good resolution, but that seems to be a spider from the Family [Lycosidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_spider), known as *wolf spiders*, more specifically *Venatrix pictiventris*.

Here is an image for comparisson:

[image]

<sup>Source: http://www.findaspider.org.au/find/spiders/497.htm</sup>

This is the distribution of *Venatrix pictiventris* in Australia, going from Tasmania to Queensland, with most observations in New South Wales:

[image]

✻ I advocate for the protection of sharks, spiders, snakes, bats etc. So, whenever I can, I try to demystify arachnophobia. People love saying that the funnel web is deadly and so on, but for you to have a better idea, moths (e.g. [*Lonomia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonomia_obliqua#Toxicity)) kill more people than spiders.

Comment: Thanks! The photo you provided looks very similar to the guy that got me.